# How to explain BEAST attack to non-tech people

Tags: tls, beast

I'm looking for the best way to describe the **B**rowser **E**xploit **A**gainst **S**SL/**T**LS (BEAST) attack to non-technical people, without being too general.

So I am not looking for: "did you ever noticed the lock in your browsing ensuring it is a secure connection?! When you are vulnerable to BEAST, it is not a secure connection anymore."

Anyone know a better way to explain this particular vulnerability to non-techies?

Comment: This may sound a little odd, but i think your 'not looking for'-explanation is actually pretty sound :) maybe you could define it in more detail, by adding another metaphor, like: 'BEAST makes your lock accept any key, just like a lock which has been modified'.

Comment: LOL, I know it is pretty sound, but I think it is too high-over. The vulnerability in that case is equal to "Heartbleed", which it obviously isn't. So a little less high-over but as understandable for non-technical people.

Comment: hmmm. i don't agree, cause heartbleed is more like... well you can explain heartbleed perfectly with this comic: https://xkcd.com/1354/

BEAST is rather a bypassing of Diffie-Hellman by being able to manipulate Alice and Bobs 'telephone', speaking in metaphors; while Heartbleed is a remote flawn in the protocol, allowing to recover sensitive information from the servers memory.

Comment: I agree with you. In a technical way, they do differ. In a non technical way, still the profound secure line, isn't secure anymore. But that is why I am looking for a way to explain BEAST in a more advanced way to non-technical people. So it is specific enough for BEAST, but not about bypassing Diffie-Hellman and other tech slang

Comment: This is a site for techies.